# What is the use of the different libraries?

Tags: c#, dll

In VS so are so many different libraries. I dont know which one to choose to create a reusable library for different projects. Can someone please explain the usage of each of the following when and why to pick which one.

Here is a list of the available libraries:

- WCF service library
- Class library (.NET Core)
- Class library (.NET Standard)
- Class library (.NET Framework)
- Class library (portable)
- Class library (universal windows)

Comment: Portable is old-style cross-platform libraries, unless you **must** make them, I would stay away from them. If you intend to use the library cross-platform I would use ".NET Standard", otherwise ".NET Framework".

Comment: By cross-platform I mean that you want your class library to be usable on Windows, Linux, macOS, Raspberry Pi, iOS, Android, etc. and some combination of those platforms.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations, can you please highlight more on why you didn't like portable and what do you mean by make?

Comment: The old "portable" class libraries relied upon profiles, which you had to install, so you could target profile X and Y and Z. The new .NET Standard targets requirements, you're not targetting Windows Phone, Windows and Linux, you're targetting any compatible platform that meets the requirements.

Comment: also will net standard work across all, like hololens, Kinect, windows, mac, Linux, Xbox, xamarin (both on mac and windows)? I'll also create a small test to use them against all.

Comment: It depends on which .NET Standard version you're targetting but yes, the point is that it should work on them all. Obviously, if you target a high .NET Standard version that supports talking to SQL Server (This is a hypothetical example, I don't know if any or which .NET Standard version would do that), then obviously you cannot use this library on a platform that doesn't have support for talking to SQL Server.

Comment: You can see the most up-to-date support matrix here: [.NET Standard Versions](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions.md)

Comment: I see net standard 1.3 and 1.4 seems good for all the latest stuff. Windows 8, phone and silver light are not my requirements at that moment. Agree?

Comment: I've a problem, I created a netstandard library 1.4 but then I created a unit test from the template -> Unit Test Project (.NET Framework) and the error I'm getting is it can't be referenced by the project that targets netframework v 4.6. So what kind of unit test template I can use to test netstandard

Comment: Look to the <== left, select a node underneath "Visual C#" to narrow down the candidates.

Comment: Hans, any specific entry? Please tell me the fully qualified name of the unit test to use against net standard library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case you should go for **Class library (.NET Framework)**. Am not sure about all of them but

- **WCF service library**: for WCF service
- **Class library (.NET Core)**: if you're targetting **.NET Core Framework**
- **Class library (universal windows)**: if you're targetting for **Windows Phone App**
- **Class library (.NET Standard)**: The .NET Standard is a formal specification of .NET APIs that are intended to be available on all .NET runtimes. [Read 
  Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library)
- **Class library (portable)**: The .NET Framework Portable Class Library project type in Visual Studio helps you build cross-platform apps and libraries for Microsoft platforms quickly and easily. [Read Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391(v=vs.110).aspx)